# Prove that $M$ is $\sigma$-algebra (Baire categories)

Tags: measure-theory, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and set $$ M :=  \{B \subset X : B \text{ is of first category or the complement of a first category set}\} $$

Prove that $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
In particular, I'm having issues dimostrating that:
$$\forall (E_i)_{i \in N} \subset M \implies\cup^{}_{i \in N}E_i \in M$$

Second question: Does $M$ contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the sets $E_i$ are of first category then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ is of first category as well. Otherwise, there is some $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $E_j^c$ is of first category. Then:

$(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i^c\subseteq E_j^c$

A subset of a first category set is of first category as well. So in all cases we get $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\in M$.

As for the second question, try looking at the case $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Many thanks mark!